Не работает Tilemap.SetTile
Проблема такая, есть скрипт в котором нужно удалять части тайлмапа при нажатии на S
для этого я задействовал raycast'ы. Сам рейкаст работает отлично, проверил через Debug.Log, а данная строка отказывалась работать напрочь.
tilemap.SetTile(tilemap.WorldToCell(_hit.collider.transform.position), null);

Весь скрипт:
using UnityEngine; using UnityEngine.Tilemaps;

namespace Player {
    public class DiggerSystem : MonoBehaviour
    {
        [SerializeField] private Tilemap tilemap;
        [SerializeField]private float destination;
        private Ray2D _ray;
        private RaycastHit2D _hit;
        void Update()
        {

            _hit = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, Vector2.down, destination, 1<<6);
            Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, Vector3.down*destination);
            
            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S))
            {
                if (_hit.collider.gameObject != null)
                {
                    Debug.Log($"Deleted: {_hit.collider}");
                    tilemap.SetTile(tilemap.WorldToCell(_hit.collider.transform.position), null);
                }
            }
        }
    } }

